# $_SESSION not carrying across php pages

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am having a problem with the `$_SESSION` function in my php website. I set the function and then try to access it in another page, but it just comes up as blank.

This is the file `login.php` where I set the `$_SESSION`

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <?php
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

  if ($email && $password){
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($numrows != 0){ 
        //username exists
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        if ($password != $row[2]){
            print 'Incorrect password<br />';
            $error = TRUE;
        }
        else {
            //password is correct
            echo "You're in! <a href='member.php'>Click</a> here to enter member page";
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        }
    }
    else {
        //email not found
        print 'Sorry, that email cannot be found.<br />';
        $error = TRUE;
    }
  }
  else {
    die('Please enter an email and password<br />');
    $error = TRUE;
  }

  if ($error){
    print '<a href=index.php>Go Back</a>';
  }
    ?>
</html>
```

And this is the `member.php` file.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['email'];
    echo "Your email is ";
    echo $username;
}
?>
```

When I press the link to go the the `member.php` page via the link, the page is completely blank, presumably suggesting that the `$_SESSION['email']` has nothing in it.

Please let me know where I am going wrong, and how to rectify the issue.
Any help would be much appreciated.

If anyone wants to see how the site is actually working, please go [here](http://benstobbs.co.uk/sxc).

Comment: in login.php u need to add session_start on the top

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){` should most likely be `if (isset($_SESSION['email'])){` --- `$_SESSION['username']` isn't defined anywhere, until you do define it. Otherwise, get rid of it.

Comment: As per your edit, change `$_SESSION['email'] = $email;` to `$_SESSION['email'] = $username;` since you're checking with `$username = $_SESSION['email'];`

Comment: Hi, I have edited my code (and my question) to include all of your edits, and still nothing! I have no idea what is going on, as these two things that I left out were of paramount importance, and still nothing! Any other ideas?!

Comment: Time for you to `var_dump();` then.

Comment: On login.php are you sure there is a value in $_POST['email']? var_dump($_POST); is handy.

Comment: when shall I call the var_dump?

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);` after any session variable; or at the end of your code. You can also check for a specific session name `var_dump($_SESSION['email']);` or `var_dump($username);` etc. as you can with a POST variable.

Comment: still not doing anything...

Comment: please see my edit to see the actual site

Comment: I think you may be overwriting your session in `member.php` using `$username = $_SESSION['email'];` try removing it. Plus, in your `login.php` you can use a chained method. Instead of `$email = $_POST['email'];` you can use `$email = $_POST['email'] = $_SESSION['email'];` that way `$email` will be both your POST and your SESSION variable.

Comment: I think I have the solution. Instead of just `$email = $_POST['email'];` in your `login.php` page, do this `$email = $_POST['email']; $_SESSION['email'] = $email;` and get rid of the `$_SESSION['email'] = $email;` under `echo "You're in!...`

Comment: yes, but I only want the session to be started once the user has successfuly logged in

Comment: That shouldn't matter. If the session is set (in `member.php`), then the user will have access. Otherwise, it won't let the user have access; plain & simple.

Comment: You can also try switching from `$_SESSION['email'] = $email;` to `$email = $_SESSION['email'];` but I don't see what good that will do. Anyway, I gave you a solution, now I must move on. Good luck with that. (*Take it up with the people who have given you answers; I've done enough.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add session_start(); before the HTML in login.php to set it

Comment: Not sure why, but this now works, perhaps it was combined with some of the other suggestions, but this now works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need this call at the very top of login.php, not halfway through.

```
 session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the very top of the login.php page:

```
<?php
session_start ();
?>
```

From the PHP documentation:

"Note:
To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser."

https://www.php.net/session_start

If that still doesn't work edit this line:

```
echo "You're in! <a href='member.php'>Click</a> here to enter member page";
```

to be like this instead:

```
echo "You're in! <a href='member.php?" . htmlspecialchars(SID) . "'>Click</a> here to enter member page";
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Z

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I still don't have any output on the member.php page! Any other suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: when I passed the SID, the login.php page just echos '0'?! Have no idea what that is about

Comment: You mean member.php page? member.php is the page we're passing the SID to.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is what I meant

Comment: please go [here](benstobbs.co.uk/sxc) to see how the site works

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with the passage of the SID, try this: `echo "You're in! <a href='member.php?" . htmlspecialchars(SID) . "'>Click</a> here to enter member page";`

Comment: try signing up for one